# entity framework update sql request error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got a weird thing with EF 6:

I try to update an entity with this code:

```
public void Update(ref CommandeVente vente)
{
    Ctx.Etat.Attach(vente.etat);
    Ctx.Entry<Dossier>(vente).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

CommandeVente Class is inherited from a DossierVente Class which is inherited too from a Dossier Class.

When I save the context the SQL request generated take very few properties of the entity, and the one modified is not in:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Dossiers]
SET [verrouile] = @0, [numDossier] = @1, [dateCreation] = @2, [dateCloture] = NULL, [tva] = @3, [PrixHT] = @4, [prixTTC] = @5
WHERE ([id] = @6)
```

Do you know this issue and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the SQL only include the properties where the values have changed?

Comment: No, the only property changed in this cas is Etat.id (FK Etat_id in SQL Table) and this property is not in the request. The properties in the example request have not changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to separate foreignkey and related entity.

In my exemple I use in my Vente Class

```
public virtual Etat etat { get; set; }
```

In this case Entity Framework must manages the foreignkey, but in my case it doesn't.

So I modified the entity to:

```
public int? etatId { get; set; }
public  Etat etat { get; set; }
```

And it's done. Now the foreignkey is correctly updated.